# Sequilize/Umzug: where to store a state of a database schema?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, umzug

So, I want to write an application which use some data migration. Where should I store a current state of db?

For example: I have a production server and my development machine. I wrote an application and 3 migrations for it. When I deploy the application server also runs 3 migrations.
Now I'm going to write the 4th migration. How does server recognize that it need to run only 4th migration and it already run previous 3 migrations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ref https://github.com/sequelize/cli

```
sequelize init:migrations
```

will generate migration folder where you need to write migrations and

There are three types of storage that you can use: sequelize, json, and none.

- sequelize : stores migrations and seeds in a table on the sequelize
  database
- json : stores migrations and seeds on a json file
- none :
  does not store any migration/seed

Comment: The stores will save state of migration